# AMD driver unzip problem

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati

So I'm trying to install the new AMD drivers but I can't seem to unzip them any idea how to do this? here is my out put

```
Archive:  amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip or
        amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip.zip, and cannot find amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Looks like a corrupted zip file to me. Can you give more details on where you found this? See if they provide instructions on how to verify the file's integrity.

Comment: Yeah sure this is were I got it from http://linuxg.net/the-amd-catalyst-13-12-drivers-for-linux-have-been-released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check your download's authenticity/validity

`md5sum amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip`

`2418a94b699fe8fdec01ccd32f684c90  amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip`

If your sum doesn't match, you need to re-download the driver (which is what I suspect).

### Download your driver

`wget --referer='http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86' http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip`

### Unzip Driver

`unzip amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip`

### Install Driver

`sudo bash amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run`

Comment: Thank for that. I'm new to Linux and I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: No problem.  I would have been lost as well, had I not had to deal with AMD and their download section for a few years, now :P

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to changing the links of Archived Drivers, or improper --referer= link.
If the --referer= link is bad, wget will sometimes download a blank corrupted zip file of the same name.
In the same token using wget without a --referer= can cause this also.

Two ways to check would be:
1. Using earthmeLon's Answer above md5sum check on the zip file itself.
2. Checking the --referer= link in a browser to make sure it's valid.